# Broken Dependencies

Tags: apt, dependencies

OS: ElementaryOS 6 Odin - Built on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

I have some problems with lib-granite dependency, probably related to elementary-tweaks.
Looking into the forum I found some topics regarding my problem but no solution in my case.

That's the error I get every time I try to update my system:

```
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    libgranite6 : Depends: lib-granite-common (>= 6.1.2+r2170+pkg121~ubuntu6.1) but 6.1.2-1 is to be installed 
    mc : Depends: mc-data (= 3:4.8.24-2ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Running the fix-broken command I get this error:

```
(Reading database ... 145521 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libgranite-common_6.1.2+r2170+pkg121~ubuntu6.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libgranite-common (6.1.2+r2170+pkg121~ubuntu6.1) over (6.1.2-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgranite-common_6.1.2+r2170+pkg121~ubuntu6.1_all.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/share/metainfo/granite.appdata.xml', which is also in package libgranite5:amd64 5.3.0-1
Errors were encountered while processing: /var/cache/apt/archives/libgranite-common_6.1.2+r2170+pkg121~ubuntu6.1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

If I try to manually purge libgranite5 or libgranite6 I get a similar dependency error.

I've already Installed Pantheon-Tweaks instead of elementary-tweaks but the error remain.
Right now I can't even install package like synaptic or similar.

Hope that someone can help me with this problem.

Comment: First aid `sudo mv /usr/share/metainfo/granite.appdata.xml $HOME` then `apt --fix-broken install` one off the 2 package has to be deinstlalled,

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I think I've solved the problem adding to your aid the command for delete libgranite5.

Comment: No you have not sove it . you have  to uninstall one of this packages!! As I wrote ist was only first aid not a solution or answer.

Comment: I've uninstalled the libgranite5 package and I've kept libgranite6.